# How do we find the distance of a point on oblate (spheroid) from its two foci ? Can anyone give example?

Tags: analytic-geometry, 3d, spherical-trigonometry

How do we find the distance of a point  on oblate (spheroid) from its two foci ?  Does it also equals to 2a like in ellipse or not? Can anyone give the example?  (Given a>b=c). In 3D ellipsoid 'a' being the semi major axis. 'b' and 'c' are semi minor axis with equal value.

Answer (score 1):

This is the fourth time you have asked the same question, but this time you provide an important extra piece of information. Since the two "minor axes" are equal the ellipsoid is a solid of revolution about the $x$ axis and the sum of the distances from the foci to any point on the ellipse is in fact the same $2a$ as in the $x$-$y$ plane.

Comment: Thank you sir, i got it

Comment: @UrdSherQaisrani  You're welcome. You can accept this answer (the check box) and upvote it if you like. You should delete the other versions that don't have answers so they don't continue to attract attention.